# Windows like website grid for my projects

Tags: css

**Hello CSS Lovers!**

I have a question for you. I would like to make a Windows like portfolio grid. Actually I allready made it myself, but it didn't work perfectly.

If you see my first example here

[image]

This is my grid as it is now. Here's the CSS:

```
article {
  width: 230px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

article.highlight {
  width: 470px;
  height: 410px;
}
```

Now, this is how I would like it to be:

[image]

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: Checkout the metrojs which is available here http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
article.highlight {
  width: 470px;
  height: 410px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 article{
 float:left;
 display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the awesome Javascript library [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which perfectly fits those squares into a flexible grid.